# Visual Code and PowerShell 5.1 Not Loading SharePoint 2013 PsSnapin

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, visual-studio-code, sharepoint-2013

I am running the latest version of Visual Code (1.37.1) on Windows 2012 server. After upgrading to PowerShell 5.1 from 4. I am getting the following error when I try to add the SharePoint PsSnapin:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Add-PsSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to change the PowerShell extension setting for PowerShell Exe Path. I actually just left the setting blank.

The bad setting was c:\windows\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe [image]